# Azure Functions outgoing HTTP call not working

Tags: c#, azure, http, azure-functions

I have an Azure Servicebus function trigger which is supposed to call an external endpoint whenever an event is placed in its designated queue. However, when the function picks up the event and is going to make the outgoing request it fails with the following log message

> Executed 'AzureServicebusTrigger' (Failed, Id=cb218eb5-300b-40c0-8a4e-81f977b9cd5c)
>   An attempt was made to access a socket in a way forbidden by its access permissions`

My function:

```
public static class AzureServicebusTrigger
{

    private static HttpClient _httpClient = new HttpClient();

    [FunctionName("AzureServicebusTrigger")]
    public static async Task Run([ServiceBusTrigger("receiver", Connection = "ServiceBusConnectionString")]
        string myQueueItem, ILogger log)
    {
        var request = await _httpClient.GetAsync("http://<ip>:7000");
        var result = await request.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
    }
}
```

What is this `permission`?

And how do I enable such that outgoing requests from my function become possible?

Comment: Just for clarification, in the code your running the `<ip>` is an actual domain or IP address correct? Also, are you running that function in Azure or localhost?

Comment: Does this fail for every call or only after a a few? Your "var request = " is actually the response not the request, and you should be closing your response once read.

Comment: @VictorP yes the `<ip>` is just a placeholder, and I am seeing this problem only when I run in Azure. It works fine on localhost.

@MurrayFoxcroft This fails for every single call from the first one.

Answer (score 2):

I have an educated guess. I've seen this before with Web Apps. It can occur if you've exhausted the number of outbound connections available for your chosen SKU in your pricing tier.

I'm guessing you're on the Azure Function consumption plan. If so, you are limited to 600 active connections ([see here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-subscription-service-limits#functions-limits)). So if you're seeing this problem intermittently, try moving to the Premium tier or an App Service plan of Standard or higher.

Answer (score 1):

I think Rob Reagan is correct. To help you accept his answer as correct I suggest the following.

Can you inspect how many function execution and servers (function host instances) did you have at the moment of the failure. You can do that by [adding Application Insights](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-monitoring) and writing such a query.

```
performanceCounters
| where cloud_RoleName =~ 'YourFunctionName'
| where timestamp > ago(30d)
| distinct cloud_RoleInstance
```

Or by reproducing the load and watching [live monitor](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/app/live-stream).